# How to destroy webbrowser element and readd with same id?

Tags: c#, wpf, browser, runtime

Is that possible to destroy webbrowser object and re add it to the application. I think destroying is easy part but i need to recompose it and add to the application with same ID.

Is this possible?

Comment: What is the "ID" that you're talking about?

Comment: I mean the object name. You know you give a name when composing object.

Comment: Are you talking about the name you give it in XAML? I'm not getting you...